# Dynamic config for Grunt task

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to change a boolean value based on the task called.

For example, given this task definition inside the `grunt.initConfig` block:

```
myTask:{
  options:{
    someConfig:doTheAction
  },
  build:{...}
}
```

The `doTheAction` var is defined above the `grunt.initConfig` block. (e.g. `var doTheAction=true;`).

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
grunt.registerTask('prod','Production',function()
{
    doTheAction=true;
    grunt.task.run('default');
});
grunt.registerTask('prod','Production',function()
{
    doTheAction=false;
    grunt.task.run('default');
});
```

The issue is that while `doTheAction` changes value, the `myTask`'s option `someConfig` is set to the init value of that var.

How can I make `someConfig` change based on the task called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I do it using `grunt.config` :

```
var taskConfig = {
    pkg: {
        var1: null
    },
    myTask:{
        options:{
            someConfig     : '<%= pkg.var1%>',
            someOtherConfig: grunt.config.get('pkg.var1') //alternative
        },
        build:{...}
    }
}

grunt.registerTask('prod','Production',function()
{
    grunt.config.set('pkg.var1', true);
    grunt.task.run('default');
});
grunt.registerTask('prod','Production',function()
{
    grunt.config.set('pkg.var1', false);
    grunt.task.run('default');
});
```

Hope this helps